# Retrieve 5th highest salary in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get the 5th highest salary from the table. Suppose, I have 100 rows and I want to display details of 5th highest salary of the individual then how to write that query in T-SQL using SQL Server 2008R2.

```
1 emp1 1000
2 emp2 2000
3 emp3 3000
4 emp4 4000
5 emp5 5000
6 emp6 6000
7 emp7 7000
8 emp8 8000
9 emp9 9000
```

Comment: What should happen on ties?

Comment: This a bad question. Will everyone have different salaries? How at ties handled at places 1-4+ At 5+? Is is DENSE_RANK or RANK you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
with salaryCTE AS
 (
 select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by AnnualSalary desc) AS Ranking,*
 from salary -- employe salary table
  )
 select * from salaryCTE where Ranking=5
```

Comment: how about ties? Use [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) instead.